# Android radiogroup horizontal alignment contents not visible

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout xml looks like

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I am creating radiogroup and adding radiobuttons through code

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);           
        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
        rg.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rg.setOrientation(0);
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            final String drinkname = itr.next();
            System.out.println("drinkname: "+drinkname);
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
            rb.setText(drinkname);              
            rg.addView(rb);
        }
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                //group.clearCheck();

                int id = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton selectrb = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
                System.out.println(selectrb.getText().toString());
                WebMenu.drinkname = selectrb.getText().toString();


            }
        });
        ll.addView(rg);
```

It is supposed to show 6 values; But it is showing only 3 properly and remaining looks like hidden. Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you please add a picture?

Comment: Your code is working ok. Are you sure your iterator has 6 elements?

Comment: @joao2fast4u - SO is not allowing to add a pic. I have added in dropbox. Please find the link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/kju5uawmsfxhome/SO1.png?dl=0

Comment: @joao2fast4u - Yes! iterator has 6 elements.

Comment: The 3 remaining buttons are being displayed but are out of the screen. How would you want them to appear? Below the other 3?

Comment: @joao2fast4u - Yes! I want them to be like 3 in a row. But both of the rows should allow me only one selection.

Comment: But the problem is that, both the rows are independent.

Comment: See my edited answer. Now, selecting one button in a RadioGroup will clear the selection of the other RadioGroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current `RadioGroup` class implementation, you cannot have two rows of `RadioButtons`. 
So, either you set an `HorizontalScrollView` to your layout and allow the user to scroll to see all the `RadioButtons` or you use two `RadioGroups`, each of them containing 3 `RadioButtons`.

So, using your example (with little variations), this last solution can be implemented like this:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);           
    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    RadioGroup rg2 = new RadioGroup(this);
    rg.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    rg2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rg2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    String [] drinks = new String [] {"Mountain Dew", "7Up", "Root Beer", "Pepsi", "Cola", "Ice Tea"};
    int i = 0;

    while(i<drinks.length){
        final String drinkname = drinks[i];
        Log.i(TAG, "drinkname: "+drinkname);
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
        rb.setText(drinkname);  
        if(i %2==0)
            rg.addView(rb);
        else
            rg2.addView(rb);
        i++;
    }

    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            //unselect all radios in the other RadioGroup
            if(rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=-1){
                rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                rg2.clearCheck();
                rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            }

            int id = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton selectrb = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
            if(selectrb != null){
                Log.i(TAG,selectrb.getText().toString());
                WebMenu.drinkname = selectrb.getText().toString();
            }


        }
    });

    rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            //unselect all radios in the other RadioGroup
            if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=-1){
                rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                rg.clearCheck();
                rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            }

            int id = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton selectrb = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
            if(selectrb != null){
               Log.i(TAG,selectrb.getText().toString());
               WebMenu.drinkname = selectrb.getText().toString();
            }


        }
    });

    ll.addView(rg);
    ll.addView(rg2);
```

You just have to be careful with the fact that your two `RadioGroups` keep track of only 3 `RadioButtons` each. They do not communicate with each other and do not affect each other. So if you select one `RadioButton` from the first row (first `RadioGroup`), you still have your selection on the second `RadioGroup` and vice-versa. You have to manage this situation yourself.

**Edit:** One way to manage this is unselecting all the `radioButtons` in RadioGroup1, when we select one `RadioButton` in RadioGroup2 and vice-versa. I have added code to do that.